# Mule deployment based on Jenkins Jobs

Tags: mule

I have  a Zip file exported by Mule Studio. Need to deploy it on Mule Server using Jenkin Jobs. Please provide the Steps.

I am having mule enterprise standalone 3.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Mule [apps deployment](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Deployment) apps is just as simple as most the other container ones. Just copy the zip to an APP folder. If you have an scp tool, there you go.

Of course this only applies to the community edition, enterprise edition is bundled with more sophisticated mechanisms of monitoring/management.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with Victor here, however, you can use the MMC agent REST APIs also to deploy the apps directly to the mule platform which will also add the build into the repository.

You just need to look for an option how to place the zip in the $MULE_HOME/apps.